# Calling Web Service Function returns List (Of String) from Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, web-services, list, asmx

I have a Web Service with multiple functions that do a job with SQL Server 2012 database. My aim is to have a Windows Service that uses this web service functions to select and insert to a database.

The current web service have different functions types that returns boolean, string or list of string. Everything works fine except when calling function that returns list of string  getGames () from a Windows Form. (Windows Form as a replica for Windows Service)

Error: Value of type '1-dimensional array of Object' cannot be converted to 'System.collections.generic.list(Of String)'

From the Windows Form project I added a web service - Add Service Reference > Advanced > Add Web Reference. I am still a student so I don't have much experience on web services. Windows Service is created on Framework 3.5 and Windows Form on Framework 4.5 (not sure if this makes a difference)
Error:

```
listOfGames = ws.getGames("username123", "password123") '** Error Here
```

Here's the web service function

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function getGames(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim m As DBMember = DBMember.verifyUsername(username, password)
    If m IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim gList As New List(Of String)
        gList = DBGame.selectAllGames()
        Return gList
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Here's how I'm calling the web service function:

```
    Private Sub onStart()
    Dim ws As localhost.Service1 = New localhost.Service1
    listOfGames = ws.getGames("username123", "password123") '** Error Here
End Sub
```

Here's the query:

```
 Shared Function selectAllGames() As List(Of String)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT g_Exe FROM Game"
    cmd.Connection = DB.Conn()

    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim gList As New List(Of String)

    If rdr.HasRows Then
        While rdr.Read
            gList.Add(rdr.Item("g_Exe").ToString())
        End While
    End If

    DB.CloseDB()
    Return gList
End Function
```

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Hi John, So by using WCF, I should be able to communicate with database such as web service from client? thanks.

Comment: Yes. WCF completely replaces the functionality of ASMX web services, and then adds a lot of functionality ASMX never had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that happens is because your web service is not returning an actual .NET `List` object, it's simply returning an XML representation of the list using the standard SOAP format for lists.  As such, the type used to return the data on the client-side is completely determined by the code on the client.

When you add a reference to a web service, Visual Studio automatically generates proxy classes for you.  The proxy classes are client-side replicas of the web methods defined on the server-side.  However, for lists, the client-side has no way of knowing what specific .NET type of list was returned by the web method.  As far as it knows, the web service may not have even been written in a .NET language as all.  Therefore, it has to arbitrarily pick a way to represent the data in the proxy class.  The default list type that is used in proxy classes is simple arrays.

When you are added the reference to the web service, if you add it as a *Web Reference*, you are not given an option to specify the type to use for lists.  *Web References* always use arrays for lists.  If, however, you are adding the reference as *Service Reference*, then you can change the type that will be used in the proxy classes to represent lists.  To do so, when adding the reference, click the *Advanced* button.  Then, in the *Data Type* section change the *Collection type* from `System.Array` to `System.Collections.Generic.List`.

If you are stuck leaving your proxy classes using arrays, you can still make it work by simply converting the array to a `List`, like this:

```
Dim listOfGames As New List(Of String)()
listOfGames.AddRange(ws.getGames("username123", "password123"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Steve it worked by converting it to an array.

        Dim listOfGames As New List(Of String)()

        listOfGames.AddRange(ws.getGames("***", "**"))
        For Each i In listOfGames
            lstStartUp.Items.Add(i)
        Next